# Ansible fails to compare version with is version

Tags: ansible

I use Ansible 2.8.5.  I could use `ansible_facts.package`  but simple, let's use the following playbook.

```
  - debug:
     msg: "{{ { 'version':'5.52.2' } is version('6.0.0','>=') }}"
```

returns

```
   ..."msg" : True
```

How can I get a correct dot separated version  correctly compared?

I read the official documentation and did not manage to understand how the function `version` is working.  Some people even said that this should rise a `TypeError` exception.  Nobody seems to understand how `version` is designed to work...

Comment: You're comparing a **dict** with the `version` filter, which is very likely not what you want -- although I'm equally sad that it said `True` and not `TypeError`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. refer [Version Comparison](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#version-comparison). Provide the version in the string.

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
            version1: "5.52.2"
            version2: "6.0.0"
    - debug:
            msg: "{{ version1  is version( version2  , '>=') }}"
```

Comment: I cannot grasp anything in this documention beause of the question.  I personnally disagree that `10.5.6`is a lower version than `9.5.6 `.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you `register` the version first in a variable and then add a check. Then you can compare the content of the variable. Here is an example -

```
failed_when: "'<version>{{ version }}</version>' not in this.content"
    - debug: msg=" version is {{ this.content.split('\n')[0].split('version')[1].split('>')[1].split('</')[0]}}"
```